# Clicking on an element to reveal additional .get information

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, get

I'm trying to work through the 2nd question on [this set of problems](http://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/lessons/continuing-legislator-lookup). I have to be able to click on a legislator's name and have additional information about him/her show up. [Here's what I have so far](http://jsfiddle.net/jupiterjazz/Qj9ED/).

```
$(function() {
  $("form#get-zip").submit(function() {
  var zip = $("input#zip").val();
  $.get("http://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/legislators/locate?apikey=191e116b2a244fb48c5028e8f370488b&zip=" + zip, function(responseText) {
    responseText.results.forEach(function(legislator) {
      $("ul#legislators").append("<li>" + " " + legislator.first_name + " " + legislator.last_name + " (" + legislator.chamber + ")" + "</li>");
      $("li").click(function() {
        $(this).append("<p>Party: " + legislator.party + ", District: " + legislator.district + "</p>");
      });
    });      
  });
  return false;
 });
});
```

The problem is that when I click on a legislator's name it reveals information about all the legislators in the list rather than the particular legislator I clicked on. This is my first experience with A.P.I.s and I'm very much still a novice programmer. I'm finding all these moving parts to be very mentally exhausting. So I really appreciate any help I can get with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest building out all your html on submit, even the details that appear below each legislator. Then hide all that extra detail. And set up the function of your li's to show the relative details.

```
$(function() {
    $("form#get-zip").submit(
       function() {
           var zip = $("input#zip").val();
           $.getJSON("http://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/legislators/locate?apikey=191e116b2a244fb48c5028e8f370488b&zip=" + zip,
               function(responseText) {
                   $.each(responseText.results,
                       function(i,legislator) {
                           var newEl = $("<li>" + " " + legislator.first_name + " " + legislator.last_name + " (" + legislator.chamber + ")" + "<p>Party: " + legislator.party + ", District: " + legislator.district + "</p></li>");
                           newEl.appendTo("ul#legislators");
                           $("ul#legislators li").last().find("p").hide(); //  hide the last added one
                       });  // end each
               });   // end get function   
       });  // end submit function
    $("ul#legislators").on("click", "li",
         function() {
             var details = $(this).find("p");
             if (details.is(":visible")) {
                 details.hide();
             } else {
                 details.show();
             }
         });  // end click function
});  // end document ready function
```

Answer (score 0):

When the click event fires, the legislator variable no longer contains the data you looking for.